# Where is the class and class's method stored?

Tags: c++, oop

The memory can be divided 4 area.

First is stack, second is heap, third is code and last is data.

I wonder where is the class and class's method stored.

Could you explain this?

Comment: If my memory serves me well, it depends on the context where you pertain the word "memory".

Comment: If you want to split memory into these particular areas (not sure how accurate that is), classes are probably "code".

Comment: One could argue that the class does not exist in the final executable (they are conceptually only part of the source). Though instances of the class go wherever data is stored.

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Is this about memory segmentation? In that case the answer depends on the architecture and the OS. On 32 bit (x86), there are usually: code segment, stack segment and one or more data segments. The heap is then part of a data segment, but how these segments are used depends on the operating system as well. On x86_64 memory segmentation isn't even used. Or is the question about C++? From a C++/language point of view, these categories don't exist. There is static, local and dynamic allocation instead (and external or internal linkage for functions).

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: in theory parts of this answer could vary widely (though, in fact, there's a fair level of uniformity across at least most typical/common implementations). So, parts of this answer are based primaily on what you can typically expect, even though more variation is possible.

"Methods" (member functions) are code, located with other code. The primary difference from other functions is that a member function typically expects to receive a hidden parameter (referred to as `this`) that gives it the address of any the object's data (including, indirectly, the class' vtable pointer).

The location of the class' data will typically depend on how the object of the class is allocated, about like any other variable: a global or static local object will be allocated statically (out of your list, apparently "data"); an local automatic variable will be allocated automatically (aka "on the stack"), and a dynamically allocated variable will be allocated (big surprise) dynamically (aka, "on the heap").

Of course, it's possible to bend those rules a bit -- for example, a `static` member variable will be allocated statically, regardless of how the rest of the object is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Methods do not take up instance storage. OOP creates the illusion a certain method is a class member object, but this is just a paradigm, in reality you can think of member methods as global functions that are only visible in the scope of objects they are "associated with".

In short, a C++ member method `SomeType.someMethod()` is identical to a C `SomeType` struct and an accompanying `SomeType_someMethod(SomeType* self)`, which is what the C++ compiler generates automatically.

The only parts of a class that actually take instance data space are non-static member types. So member methods logically occupy the "code" and "data" portions of memory, since a method is exactly that - a list of instructions and references to global and local objects in memory.

Since C++ allows for recursion and all the other "dynamic features" every instance of a function instantiates its own local objects, so the non-static and non-const local automatic members are copied from global memory to the stack, either in the form of immediate values or references to global static data. This only applies to non-const local member data, the a method does not change its instructions, so unlike locals, only one instance of the method code is needed.

So, to wrap it up, member methods, much like static member objects do not take up instance space, however, they may take up stack space when they are called, and could even lead to stack overflow in recursive situations.

EDIT: Also may be worth noting that in the case of virtual methods, that will take up one void pointer space from each object to hold the virtual table. Also most multiple inheritance implementations will commonly use multiple vtables.

Comment: "non-static and non-const method members are copied from global memory to the stack" -- That's not what happens. If by "method members" you mean data-members of the object, they are not copied to the stack. They are accessed (through the `this` pointer) at wherever they are already; this may be on the stack (if the object has automatic storage) or somewhere else. On the other hand, if by "method members" you mean local variables: They are constructed right on the stack. There is no copying from "global memory" required.

Comment: @jogojapan - I don't mean the class data members, I mean the "members" of the member method, e.g. the local automatic objects. And you say "constituted right on the stack" but considering they mostly come from immediate values, they are in practice copied from program memory to the stack, which is exactly what I had in mind. Not like an explicit `memcpy`.

Comment: How a local variable is initialized depends on, well, how it is initialized. They may be copied from other local objects, or from objects somewhere on the heap.

Comment: Whatever the source, its location is still a compile time known memory offset referenced through either a local or a global. You cannot escape the fact that whatever you do, some static data is available and whenever you do it, it gets temporarily copied to the current context. It may not technically be "copy n bytes from x to y" but is instead distributed in the form of immediate values (primitive values, offsets, e.g. stuff that fits in instructions) stored in the program code and references to the static global memory. When it uses stack space, it is technically copied from global memory.

Comment: If your point is that every part of memory (stack, heap, code, data all alike) is part of global memory, and therefore any local variable (if it is initialized at all) gets its initial value copied from "global memory", then you are right. But what's the point of answering this question, if you don't make any distinction between stack, heap etc. anyway?

Comment: The heap ... I don't think there is any way to reference it without a local, so I am not really concerned with the heap, as far as I am concerned, whatever references the heap is either a global or an automatic local. The point is answering where is the class method stored - in the global static memory, and not in the "instance" memory like the class instance itself.

Comment: "Methods do not take up instance storage." They do. Class with virtual method is bigger than class without virtual methods. Because vfptr takes space. " is identical to a C" Once again, virtual methods. " that will take up one void pointer" Incorrect. If you use multiple inheritance, there may be more than one virtual method table pointer.

Comment: @SigTerm - yes, you are right, I understand most multiple inheritance use multiple virtual tables, I incorrectly assumed the opposite, because logically, multiple vtables are not required.

Answer (score 0):

A class's definition is stored in the code section of a program (if you think about it, that would make sense, because the definition is a effectively a set of functions that conceptually take the object as an additional parameter named "this"). However, each instance of a virtual class needs to contain a pointer to its virtual table (in order to be able to perform dynamic dispatch), and that will reside wherever that instance happens to be allocated (which, for the virtual case, will typically be on the heap).

Those who are language lawyer sticklers will point out that the C++ standard doesn't dictate things like the heap and stack. I'm well aware of that, but for all practical purposes, that's how it's going to work.